# Automatically attaching the logged in user to a post he/she creates

Tags: python, django

What a want to do: When a user is logged in, and he or she makes a post, the name of that user should automatically be assigned in my database posts.

What it's doing: It's not adding a user automatically, but i am able to assign a user manually, so I'm accessing the user database, and seeing whom i can attach to a newly made post.

My question is then, how can i get this process done automatically?

Here is my code from the model.py in the posts app:

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals
from django.conf import settings
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
User = settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL

class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    content = models.TextField()
    #email = models.EmailField(null=True, blank=True, default=None)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, null=True,)
    #upload = models.FileField(null=True, blank=True, default=None)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, auto_now_add=False)
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, auto_now_add=False)

    def __str__(self):
    return self.title

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse("posts:detail", kwargs={"id":self.id})

    class Meta:
        ordering = ["-timestamp", "-updated"]
```

I am getting the user class via User = settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL and the AUTH_USER_MODEL is referring in settings.py to a class called MyUser in another models.py who originates from an app called accounts.
here is the code from that class:

```
class MyUser(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    email = models.EmailField(_('email address'), unique=True)
    first_name = models.CharField(_('first name'), max_length=30, blank=True)
    last_name = models.CharField(_('last name'), max_length=30, blank=True)
    is_admin = models.BooleanField(_('staff status'), default=False,
        help_text=_('Designates whether the user can log into this admin site.'))

    is_active = models.BooleanField(_('active'), default=True,
        help_text=_('Designates whether this user should be treated as '
    'active. Unselect this instead of deleting accounts.'))
    date_joined = models.DateTimeField(_('date joined'), default=timezone.now)

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
```

Here is the code from views.py in the posts app:

```
 def post_create(request):
    form = PostForm(request.POST or None)

    if form.is_valid():
        instance = form.save(commit=False)
        instance.save()

        # Message succes
        messages.success(request, "Succesfully Created ")
        return HttpResponseRedirect(instance.get_absolute_url())
    else:
        messages.error(request, "Not Succesfully created")

    context = {
        'form': form,
    }

    return render(request, app_name+"/post_form.html", context)
```

Here is the forms.py in the posts app:

```
from django import forms

from .models import Post

class PostForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = {
            "title",
            "content",
            "user",
            #"email",
            #"upload",
        }
```

Here are two pictures to illustrate my problem:
[The post create site](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EX6n3.png)
[The django administration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f2zIb.png)

Let me now if any more code is needed, appreciate any feedback as well.

I don't have a lot of rep on stack overflow so please let me know if this is poorly explained, and i shall re right it.

Comment: Can you include code about how you create the Post and fill in the user? If you want to do something automatically system wide, that may belong to your middleware.

Comment: Added the post_create and form, was thinking that my mistake was that i did't include the 'user' in the PostForm, but the issue remains, gonna upload a picture so you can see.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply change:

```
instance = form.save(commit=False)
instance.save()
```

to

```
instance = form.save(commit=False)
if request.user.is_authenticated():
    instance.user = request.user
instance.save()
```

Comment: ofc. Apsolutely amazing!! Works like a charm. I am in debt to you.

Answer (score 0):

If user is logged in, i think the Combobox should not 
appear, so you can do that on forms.py

forms.py

```
class PostForm(forms.ModelForm):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
       self.user = kwargs.pop('user')
       super(PostForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
       if not self.user.is_authenticated():
           self.fields['user'] = forms.ModelChoiceField(
                                    required=True, 
                                    queryset=User.objects.all())

    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = {
            "title",
            "content",
            # "user",
            #"email",
            #"upload",
        }
```

on views.py

```
def post_create(request):
    form = PostForm(request.POST or None, user = request.user)

    if form.is_valid():
        if request.user.is_authenticated():
            form.instance.user = request.user
        form.save()

        ...


    return render(request, app_name+"/post_form.html", context)
```

If you want the Combobox has selected with the user logged in, you can pass initial data on views.py, like this:

```
def post_create(request):
     if request.method == 'GET':
           form = PostForm(initial = {'user' : request.user})
```

Comment: The above solution is working, i will idd check this out as well, thanks for sharing!